# Get each input into each div onClick - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, each

How do i get **each()** input value inside a div into the innerHTML of **each()** div onClick? I want to use each() or something similar because i need to scale this up to multiple tabs and rows, this is what i have so far.

Event trigger:

```
<input type='radio' name='tab' id='tab1'>
<label for='tab1'>Tab 1</label>
```

Input:

```
<div class='row' id='tab1-container'>
    <div class='cell'>
        <input type='text'>
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
        <input type='text'>
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
        <input type='date'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div class='row' id='preview1'>
    <div class='cell'></div>
    <div class='cell'></div>
    <div class='cell'></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#tab1", function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#tab1-container .cell input').each(function () {
            input = $(this).val();
            $('#preview1 .cell').html(input);
        });
    });
});
```

Learning JQuery, what am i doing wrong here?
see my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GSnqR/7/

**Solution** 
I went for (courtesy of Jackson but without the find() function), this allows me to get **all** the inputs and dump them on to a preview tab:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab', function () {
    var inputs = $('.tab-container .cell input');
    var outputs = $('.preview .cell');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
        var value = $(inputs[i]).val();
        $(outputs[i]).html(value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't use `each()`, but it does basically the same thing. (Also, `for` loops are way faster in JS.)

```
var inputs = $('#tab1-container .cell input');
var outputs = $('#preview1 .cell');
$('#tab1').on('click', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
        var value = $(inputs[i]).val();
        $(outputs[i]).html(value);
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EdqxG/1/

And if you wanted to extend this to work for more tabs than just "tab1"...

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var inputs = $this.find('.tab-container .cell input');
    var outputs = $this.find('.preview .cell');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
        var value = $(inputs[i]).val();
        $(outputs[i]).html(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: You legend. I didn't realise you could select all elements like that; i thought each() was required to select all elements. Thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome! `each()` can still be useful--sometimes--but in this case, the iteration count was important.

Comment: Wow. How does this work? It finds the closest 'tab-container' and '.preview' to '.tab' and populates '.preview .cell'?

Comment: It's untested, but that's what it's supposed to do. (Assuming you contain each `.tab-container` and `.preview` in a respective `.tab`.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

http://jsfiddle.net/pmcalabrese/U6tQQ/

couple of suggestions:

1) avoid id attribute with square brackets

2) use example as start from the superb jquery documentation

```
$(document).on("click", "#tab1", function () {
    elements = $('#preview0 .cell');
    $(function () {
        $('#tab1-container .cell input').each(function (index) {
            input = $(this).val();
            $(elements[index]).html(input);
        });
    });
});


$(".row .cell input").on('keyup change', function () {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        //At least one input is empty
        $(this).parent().siblings().children("button").hide();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().siblings().children("button").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work the way i want it,  the button hide/show is meant to check if all the inputs are not blank, your method unhides them when one is full, and the each function doesn't put values into the bottom preview. I am going to go with Jacksons answer. Thanks though.